# Joomla Mailto Component unable to send mails occassionally

Tags: joomla

Greetings,
I will certainly hope someone will be able to provide some enlightenment to my problem.
Currently, I have 2 joomla sites, layout and menus are a replicate of the other.

I noticed that on both Joomla, I will occasionally encounter "Unable to send mail" after a form submission.

Is this the fault of my server, or the fault of Joomla's PHP Mailer ? I will certainly love to approach my hosting company for a solution but I do not want to place a false accusation on them.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Joomla will use PHP's `mail()` function, although you can set it to use other methods (sendmail, SMTP) in the Global Configuration on the Server tab.

The best way to test this would be to set up a small PHP script that sends a message through `mail()`. Next time you see the message, try running the small script and see if that one fails as well.

Answer (score 0):

I personally preffer using an SMTP server for mailing purpose. I guess your hosting company has provided something like smtp.yourdomain.com
You may use it.
Else, you can use the gmail server smtp.gmail.com
It wont disappoint you for sure.